# Extruding only some segments of a cylinder with subdivision mod creates weird artifacts and gaps

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, bevel

- I have a shape I created from a cylinder.
- It's wider at the top.
- I have a bevel modifier applied.
- I have subdivision modifier applied.

I am trying to extrude incomplete ring of faces along normals, like this:
[image]

With the modifiers, this results in artifacts around the corners and gaps, where the extruded part doesn't look attached to the part below it:
[image]

[image]

What would be the best way to deal with this? I have tried a few things like beveling the edge connecting the shapes, separating the mesh, adding ring loops... with no luck.

Here is the file: [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome! please share your file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: just did. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this kind of topology, but I've added vertical edge loops on this part (like if it was a 32 vertices cylinder) in order to avoid bad shading:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! thank you for the answer! Could you elaborate a bit? It looks like you beveled the edges maybe?

Comment: Yes and once you've bevelled you need to create the topology I show in the second picture. Maybe use a Shrinkwrap on some of a vertices with a cylinder as target and your vertices as vertex group so that your vertices keep a nice round shape

Comment: Thanks. I've been messing around with it and i guess i don't know enough yet to be able to replicate this yet. Will accept if I don't get other suggestions

Comment: Nevermind, i watched a bunch of videos on redirecting edge flow and was able to do this. Thanks!

Comment: oh ok great, sorry for not being more helpful, it's a bit complicated to explain the whole thing in Blender Stack Exchange, you're right videos are much better to understand

Comment: No worries! you put me on the right track